# void указатель или произвольные данные

Tags: c, void

У меня есть список, в узлах списка лежат ключ и данные, ключ - char*, данные - void*.

То есть мне нужно хранить произвольные данные. Допустим я добавил в список ключ, а в данные занес какое-то число или тоже строку. В будущем я хочу посмотреть что лежит в этом узле и получить это. Как мне преобразовать данные из void указателя обратно в то, чем они являлись при внесении в список? Или что-то другое нужно использовать для хранения произвольных данных вообще?

Comment: Вам нужно рядом в каком то виде (например, просто число или enum) сохранить указание на то, что там хранится

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошо, если у меня там число, как void обратно в int переделать? Ну или в строку, если там строка?)

Comment: просто взять и кастануть. в зависимости от того, как туда поместили. для строки, скорее всего `(char*) p`, для числа могут быть варианты - `(int)p` или `*(int*)p`

Comment: Или использовать уже готовый тип `std::any`, который хранит значение и его тип. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: @DmitryK, с чего вы взяли, что можно C++ использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim, можно ли как-то подобное реализовать с union? И если да, то что все таки лучше, union или *void (с хранением типа в другой переменной для обозначения)?

Comment: В случае с union все равно нужно хранить переменную, которая будет указывать нужный тип. Если вариантов того, что будет хранится, немного, union хорошая идея. Если вариантов много, а размер занимаемой памяти имеет значение - тогда лучше `struct { int type; void* data}` (ну или enum)

Comment: @KoVadim, понял, спасибо :)